# LibreOffice Calc fix the size (# lines) of input line

Tags: libreoffice

I am using *LibreOffice Calc 6.1* under Ubuntu. Every time I start Calc, the size of the *input line* (the area where we enter values or formulas) is set to a **single line**. I can click the down arrow at the far right or just drag the border below the input line further down to expand it to more than one line. I would like this to be permanent. However, each time I exit and restart Calc (even with the same spreadsheet) this area is returned back to a single line. Is there a hidden option to set this area to a fixed size, say 3 lines?

Comment: I am now on LibreOffice 6.2, but still the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What about LibreOffice 6.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug ("enhancement") report in: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137849

Any other people that want this enhancement to be implemented in new versions of Calc can comment there.

I will update my answer once a new development happens.

---

### Update:

This feature was added in version 7.4 and the information is stored "per document".